# Having some trouble with File I/O

Tags: java

I have a homework assignment to read data from a file which contains names and scores per game of basketball players. The program is supposed to output the names and scores of the players, as well as tally each player's average score per game, and finally display the player with the highest average. I am currently stuck on trying to get the average and a newline character for each player.

[Here is a pic](https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-9/1379989_10152478294323932_1931326649055391994_n.jpg?oh=4a127d414fbb7afaf7488d4531e7664f&oe=54E4B520&__gda__=1424190489_e403443c6287d05db6f9b9967238ac20) of the input file I am reading the data from.

and here is my code:

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class BasketballTeam
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            File f = new File("BasketballData.txt");
        
            if (f.exists())
            {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
                int games = 0;
                int totalScore = 0;
                double avg = 0.0;
            
                while (input.hasNext())
                {
                    String s = input.next();
                    System.out.printf("%-9s", s);
                    int a = input.nextInt();
                    while (input.hasNextInt())
                    {
                        if (a == -1)
                        {
                            avg = (double)totalScore/games;
                            System.out.printf("%14s%.2f\n", "Average of ", avg);
                            games = 0;
                            totalScore = 0;
                            s = input.next();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.printf("%5s", a);
                            games++;
                            totalScore = totalScore + a;
                            a = input.nextInt();
                        }
                    }                       
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run the program, my output is just a single line that looks like:

```
Smith       13   19    8   12Badgley      5Burch       15   18   16Watson......and so on
```

Why am I not getting any newline characters or my average? I want my output to look like this:

```
Smith       13   19    8   12   Average of 13
Badgley      5   Average of 5
Burch       15   18   16   Average of 16.33
.....and so on
```

Thanks in advanced for any suggestions/corrections.

Comment: The link to the picture is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BasketballTeam
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File f = new File("BasketballData.txt");

        if (f.exists())
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
            int games = 0;
            int totalScore = 0;
            double avg = 0.0;

            while (input.hasNext())
            {
                String s = input.next();
                System.out.printf("%-9s", s);
                while (input.hasNextInt())
                {
                    int a = input.nextInt();
                    if(a != -1)
                    {
                        System.out.printf("%5s", a);
                        games++;
                        totalScore = totalScore + a;
                    }
                }
                avg = (double)totalScore/games;
                System.out.printf("%14s%.2f\n", "Average of ", avg);
                games = 0;
                totalScore = 0;
                System.out.println();
            }
            input.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is what you are looking for.  You don't even need the -1 at the end of each line in the file you can get rid of that if you want unless it is part of the specification.  It will work without the -1.  Your inner loop you just want to add up your totals then outside of the inner loop get your average and display.  Then reset your variables.  You were pretty close just needed to change a couple things.  If you have any questions on how this works just ask away.  Hope this helps!

Comment: This code works, many thanks! I think I was just nesting things unnecessarily and muddied things up must be. Thank you again, very much appreciated!

Comment: I marked as correct, but since this dumb website requires rep to do almost anything I can't upvote it. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using a `FileReader`:

```
File file = new File("/filePath");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fr);
//and so on...
```

Comment: We haven't covered that in class, it is an intro to java class. For file i/o the only things we have talked about are using the Scanner class and making the file the input for that for input, and then using the PrintWriter class for output. Besides, my program reads the data just fine the way it is right now, I just don't know why it won't calculate an average and throw a newline character in.

Comment: This should be at most a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
avg = ((double)totalScore/(double)games);
```

and replace \n with \r\n:

```
System.out.printf("%14s%.2f\r\n", "Average of ", avg);
```

Comment: Nope, nothing changed. But just for the sake of knowledge, what was the \r for?

Comment: @RyanJensen look at my answer it is what you are looking for.

Comment: \r is "carriage return" and a newline in Windows is usually written with a carriage return then a new line, \r\n, and on unix only a newline, \n. If you want to be really platform independent you can use System.getProperty("line.separator");

Answer (score 0):

In this line `a = input.nextInt()`, you already advance to the next int, so the test `input.hasNextInt()` will be false when you reach -1.

One possible solution is to change the loop to:

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
    String s = input.next();
    System.out.printf("%-9s", s);
    int a = 0;
    while (input.hasNextInt()) {
        a = input.nextInt();
        if (a == -1) {
            avg = (double) totalScore / games;
            System.out.printf("%14s%.2f\n", "Average of ", avg);
            games = 0;
            totalScore = 0;
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%5s", a);
            games++;
            totalScore = totalScore + a;
        }
    }
}
```